# Access Aurelia custom attribute function from within nested HTML elements

Tags: html, mvvm, data-binding, typescript, aurelia

I have a View/View-Model pair that implements a popover custom attribute. My specific goals include dismissing the popover upon both button click within the popover itself, and from clicking anywhere else on the page.

I can get my doSomething() VM function to work on the element level in the view, but not within an attribute containing an element. I've explained the issue further in the code comments. I'd appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

blog.html

```
<template>
<require from="../popover/popover"></require>

...

<!-- doSomething() works here! -->
<button type='button' click.trigger='doSomething()'>ClickMe</button>

<!-- doSomething() does not work here! -->
<!-- `click.trigger`/`click.delegate` does not trigger anything, while `onclick` shows
     "Uncaught ReferenceError: doSomething is not defined" -->
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" popover="title.bind: blogpost.title; placement.bind: 'top'" 
data-content='<button type="button" click.trigger="doSomething()">ClickMe</button>' ></span>

...
</template>
```

blog.ts

```
... 
doSomething() {
    console.log('doing something');
}
```

popover.ts

```
...
bind() {
$(this.element).popover({
    title: this.title,
    placement: this.placement,
    content: this.content,
    trigger: 'click',
    html: true
    });
}
```

Comment: What popover plugin are you using?

Comment: @AshleyGrant Twitter Bootstrap, and I roughly followed this: https://www.sitepoint.com/extending-html-aurelia-io-way/

Comment: I am thinking the TemplatingEngine could be of use perhaps to give the popover button aurelia binding functionality?

Comment: I'm gonna ask Jeremy Danyow if he can help you on this. He's our binding wizard.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @AshleyGrant! It could be something simple to be honest. I've also tried messing with how I add the popover's content as I think this could possibly be the source of error... Above I use the `data-content` attribute, while `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" popover="title.bind: blogpost.title; placement.bind: 'top'; content.bind: 'my content';"></span>` also works. When I attempt to use html in the above instead of `my content`, I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.sourceExpression.connect is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

I recently went through the same problem. I'm currently working on a Bootstrap port for Aurelia, it is not done yet, and I haven't written any documentation, but the popover is already implemented.

You are more than welcome to take a look:
https://github.com/tochoromero/aurelia-bootstrap/tree/master/src/popover

The way you are trying to implement the popover is going to be very complicated (if even possible), things are going to get messy with the scopes. If you only had text then it would be fine, but you basically want to be able to put anything in the popover and have it bound to the right View-Model.

The way I solved this was having a couple of Custom Elements that represent the popover, I have AubsCustomPopover, AubsPopoverTitle and AubsPopoverContent.
With this 3 custom elements you will create the bootstrap markup for the popover, and because you are adding them directly in the view they will have the right View-Model, and you can do whatever you want inside them.

And then, there is a custom attribute, this is AubsPopover, this is the one that will be in charge of showing and hiding the custom attribute depending on the trigger action you specify (hover, click, focus, outsideClick).

The code using it looks something like this:

```
<aubs-custom-popover model.bind="customPopover">
  <aubs-popover-title>
     This is my awesome title <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  </aubs-popover-title>
  <aubs-popover-content>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" text.bind="password"   
             placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default" click.delegate="isOpen = false">
      Close
    </button>
  </aubs-popover-content>
</aubs-custom-popover>

<button class="btn btn-primary" 
     aubs-popover="custom-model.bind: customPopover; 
                   trigger: outsideClick; 
                   position: bottom;   
                   open.bind:isOpen">
     Custom Popover
</button>
```

As I said the Popover is fully implemented but I haven't written any documentation, I want to have a couple of more components before I do that.

If you want to use it, I can give you some help setting it up.

Comment: Cool, thanks for this! I'll look into the code later on and will try it out. Any set up help is welcome!

Comment: You can basically copy the classes in the popover folder and include them in your application, then just create your popover based off the example I provided. I hope I can get the bootstrap project to a good state soon so I can write the documentation